# Python dataframe add columns in groups of 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data-frame with n rows:

```
df = 1 2 3
     4 5 6
     4 2 3
     3 1 9
     6 7 0
     9 2 5
```

I want to add a columns with the same value in groups of 3. 
n (num rows) is for sure divided by 3.

So the new df will be:

```
df = 1 2 3 A
     4 5 6 A
     4 2 3 A
     3 1 9 B
     6 7 0 B
     9 2 5 B
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove last rows if not dividsable by 3 with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then create 100% unique group by divide by `3` with integer division by `3`:

```
print (df)
   a  b  d
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  4  2  3
3  3  1  9
4  6  7  0
5  9  2  5
6  0  0  4 <- removed last row

N = 3
num = len(df) // N * N
df = df.iloc[:num]
df['groups'] = np.arange(len(df)) // N
print (df)
   a  b  d  groups
0  1  2  3       0
1  4  5  6       0
2  4  2  3       0
3  3  1  9       1
4  6  7  0       1
5  9  2  5       1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, groupby:

```
df['new_col'] = df.sum(1).groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  new_col
0  1  2  3       30
1  4  5  6       30
2  4  2  3       30
3  3  1  9       42
4  6  7  0       42
5  9  2  5       42
```